# How to find a residue at z=i

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \frac{\pi \cot(\pi z)}{(1+z^2)^{2}}$. Show the residue at $z=i$ is $-\pi/4(\pi \mathrm{csch}^{2}(\pi) + \coth(\pi))$.

Then use the residue theorem to find the sum of the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+k^2)^{2}}$.

So I began doing z = i + h and substituting into f(z) then using the addition formulas.

to get: cos(PIh)cos(PIi)-sin(PIh)sin(PIi)/(sin(PIh)cos(PIi)+cos(PIh)sin(PIi)) * PI/(h^2+2hi)^2

Then I use sin(iy) = isinh(y) and cos(iy) = cosh(y)

to get: cos(PIh)cosh(PI)-isin(PIh)sinh(PI)/(sin(PIh)cosh(PI)+icos(PIh)sinh(PI)) * PI/(h^2+2hi)^2

This is where I am stuck

Comment: Latex-ified your question. Please check that is indeed what you want and finish the rest. It is hardly readable.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f$ has  a pole of order $2$ at $i$. The residue at $z=i$ is gven by the formula $\lim_{z \to i} \frac d {dz}(z-i)^{2}f(z)=\lim_{z \to i} \frac d {dz}\frac {\pi \cot (\pi z)} {(z+i)^{2}}$. Apply quotient rule to differentiate.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: @user799790 If you are happy with the above answer you should mark it as "the accepted answer"

Comment: I am happy with and have upvoted them but how do I mark it as "accepted"?